# How do I change a sum for string for it to work?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

This is my whole program I'm working on (with the function not in the right place due to the code needing to be indented) but anyway there is a problem that I'm not sure how to fix.

How do I change it so that this would work along with my program? It says that it is in a string but am not sure how to change this so it calculates the variables from the rest of my program. I am sorry seeming how this is not the only problem I am new to this and am just getting used to how this works.

```
import time
import random

def welcome():
ready="no"
while ready=="no":
    print("Welcome To Encounter Simulator Inc. Where We Provide You with combat..")
    print("Readying Start Up Sequence....")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Welcome Are You Ready? Yes or No")
    ready=input(str())
while ready!="yes" and ready!="no":
    print("Yes or No Please")
    ready=input(str())

def name():
areyousure="no"
while areyousure!="yes":
    print("What do you want your 1st character to be named?")
    name=input()
    print("Are You Sure?(yes or no)")
    areyousure=input(str())
if areyousure!="yes" and areyousure!="no":
    print("Yes or No Please")
    areyousure=input(str())
return name

 def name2():
 areyousure2="no"
 while areyousure2!="yes":
     print("What do you want your 2nd character to be named?")
     name2=input()
     print("Are You Sure?(yes or no)")
     areyousure2=input(str())
 if areyousure2!="yes" and areyousure2!="no":
    print("Yes or No Please")
    areyousure2=input(str())
 return name2

 def inputtingfor1(name):
areyousure3="no"
while areyousure3!="yes":
    print("Please Input",name,"'s Attributes..")
    skill1=input("The Skill Attribute= ")
    strength1=input("The Strength Attribute= ")
    print("Are You Sure? (Yes or No)")
    areyousure3=input(str())
return skill1,strength1

def inputtingfor2(name2):
areyousure4="no"
while areyousure4!="yes":
    print("Please Input",name2,"'s Attributes..")
    skill2=input("The Skill Attribute= ")
    strength2=input("The Strength Attribute= ")
    print("Are You Sure (Yes or No)")
    areyousure4=input(str())
return skill2,strength2

def difference1(skill1,skill2):
if skill1 >= skill2:
    result0=skill1-skill2
    result1=result0/5
elif skill1==skill2:
    print("There Will Be No Skill Modifier")
    result1=0
else:
    result0=skill2-skill1
    result1=result0/5
return result1

def difference2(strength1,strength2):
if strength1 >= strength2:
    result10=strength1-strength2
    result2=result10/5
elif strength1==strength52:
    print("There Will Be No Strength Modifier")
    result2=0
else:
    result10=strength2-strength1
    result2=result10/5
return result2

def dicerolling1():
print()
time.sleep(1)
print("This Will Determin Who Gets The Modifiers And Who Loses Them..")
dicenumber1=random.randint(1,6)
print(" The Dice Is Rolling For",name1,)
time.sleep(1)
print("And The Number",name1,"Got Was...",dicenumber1,)
return dicenumber1

def dicerolling2():
print()
time.sleep(1)
print("This Will Determin Who Gets The Modifiers And Who Loses Them..")
dicenumber2=random.randint(1,6)
print(" The Dice Is Rolling For",name2,)
time.sleep(1)
print("And The Number",name2,"Got Was...",dicenumber2,)
return dicenumber2




welcome()
name=name()
name2=name2()
skill1,strength1=inputtingfor1(name)
skill2,strength2=inputtingfor2(name2)
difference1(skill1,skill2)
difference2(strength1,strength2)
dicenumber1=dicerolling1()
dicenumber2=dicerolling2()
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing? Where and what is the error? Please be clear in your explanation of the problem.

Comment: It say unsupported opperand as using - in string but do not know how to fix etc

Comment: Are `skill1` and `skill2` strings? If so, you need to convert them to numerics.

Comment: oh yes they are thanks that may be the problem!

Comment: Please give 1.) at least 1 example of input to `difference1`, 2.) the expected output from `difference1` for those examples, 3.) a copy/paste of the error/traceback.  Right now, it is unclear what you're asking and what the exact error is.

Comment: I have now added the code and will post the error code.

Comment: line 68, in difference1
    result0=skill2-skill1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Hi there. Please don't deface questions that have been put on hold. Instead, improve them by editing and then ask for them to be re-opened. After some editing of my own, I think it is okay now, so I have cast a re-open vote.

Answer (score 1):

From the comment thread on the original question, the issue is that `skill1` and `skill2` are strings, which do not support the `-` operand. You need to cast them to `ints` before you perform any mathematical operation on them:

```
def difference1(skill1,skill2):
    try:
        s1 = int(skill1)
        s2 = int(skill2)
    except exceptions.ValueError:
        print("Could not cast to int")
        return None

    if s1 >= s2:
        result0 = s1-s2
        result1=result0/5
    elif s1==s2:
        print("There Will Be No Skill Modifier")
        result1 = 0
    else:
        result0=s2-s1
        result1=result0/5
    return result1
```

Depending on what you pass into `difference1`, you may not be left with an integer. If `skill1` and `skill2` could be parsed as `floats`, you'll hit an exception when you try to cast them to `ints`. If you know this will never be the case, you can remove the `try-except` block.

Comment: int(result0=s1-s2) => indentation error, type error

Answer (score 0):

When skill1==skill2, result1 is not defined.

fix:

```
elif skill1==skill2:
    print("There Will Be No Skill Modifier")
    return 0
```

Comment: I do not understand why one has voted "-1" : even if it is not the _only_ problem, this problem still is one !